# Calculating Monte-Carlo Error For Confidence Interval Estimation

Tags: confidence-interval, monte-carlo

I am simulating from a Categorical process such that each $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ is an independent sample. After drawing $N$ samples, I want to use my samples to estimate the standard error of the empirical confidence interval. How could I approach this problem?

Comment: Are your data categorical (nominal or ordinal), or numerical. If the observations $x_i$ lie on the real line, that ordinarily means they are numerical. If they are not assumed to be numerical, then what do you mean by standard error? // You say you have $N$ samples: Does that mean that you have one sample with $n$ observations? Or are you doing some sort of re-sampling and have $N$ re-samples of size $n?$ Is the goal to make a confidence interval (as in your title) or to find a 'standard error' (as in the text of your question)? For coherent answ, please give sample of data and state purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I will crawl very far out on a limb and **speculate** that you have
Likert-7 data from $n = 100$ subjects, and that you are making the
usual (but not always defensible) assumption that it is OK to regard
them as numerical. If this is way off target, you can use that as
a basis for refining your question. Then maybe one of us can come closer to a useful answer.

Thus your data might be something like the fictitious data simulated and described in R below:

```
set.seed(421)
x = sample(1:5, 100, rep=T, p = c(1,1,2,3,3))
table(x)
x
  1  2  3  4  5 
 14 10 20 35 21 

summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    3.00    4.00    3.39    4.00    5.00 

stripchart(x, ylim=c(.7,2.5), meth="s", pch=20)
```

[image]

**Classical approaches are questionable.** The data are pretty clearly not normal, so I am reluctant to trust
a t confidence interval $(3.13, 3.65)$ as valid. Also, there are too
many tied values to make good sense of a 95% confidence interval $(3,4)$ for the 'pseudo-median' based
on a one-sample nonparametric Wilcoxon test. I am not saying that either
of these intervals is "wrong"--only that I cannot confirm that the
assumptions underlying them are warranted.

**Nonparametric bootstrap CIs.** One kind of bootstrap confidence interval arises from taking $B = 3000$
re-samples from among the $n = 100$ scores `x`, and take the average of each re-sample. This gives a good idea of the variability of average scores
Finally, by taking quantiles 0.025 and 0.9975 of the re-sampled averages
I get a quantile 95% nonparametric CI $(3.13, 3.64)$ for the population mean Likert-5 score.

Perhaps without taking any assumed numerical meaning
of the Likert scores too seriously, we can say the the average population
scores lie between 3 and 4. [Even so, we have inevitably assumed some
numerical qualities for Likert scores: for example, that the differences
between scores 1 and 2 are as important as differences between scores 3 and 4. That these assumptions are almost routinely made in some disciplines does not mean that they are always correct or useful.]

```
set.seed(2021)
a.re = replicate(3000, mean(sample(x,100,rep=T)))
quantile(a.re, c(.025,.975))
 2.5% 97.5% 
 3.13  3.64
```

Among the 3000 re-sampled means `a.re` there only 82 uniquely distinct
values, so we should not take the second decimal places in the boundaries
of the bootstrap CI very seriously. For example, the corresponding 90% CI $(3.17, 3.61)$ and 99% CI $(3.06, 3.67)$
are not a lot different.

```
length(unique(a.re))
[1] 82

quantile(a.re, c(.05,.95))
  5%  95% 
3.17 3.61 

quantile(a.re, c(.005,.985))
 0.5% 98.5% 
 3.06  3.67
```

Here is a histogram of the 3000 resampled averages, along with the
boundaries of our 95% nonparametric bootstrap CI.

[image]

Treating Likert scores as if numerical, the point estimate of the population mean score is $\bar X = 3.39$ (in the summary table above):
if you really need a 'standard error` of this average, then you might
use $0.133.$

```
sd(a.re)
[1] 0.1327829
```

It is not very much different than the standard error of $\bar X,$ which is $S/\sqrt{n} 0.131.$ (That would be correct for normal numerical data.)

```
sd(x)/sqrt(100)
[1] 0.1309599
```

Comment: This is an amazingly rich interpretation of an otherwise unfathomable question.  Kudos for creativity; but I think we need the OP to clarify their question.

Comment: Thanks and agreed.